# Cannot find users on login screen - only guest login available

Tags: macos, mac, login

I am using OS X Mavericks and when I boot the machine I only see the guest login.
When I log in as a guest everything functions correctly but I can't access my files.. I ran OSX utilities and all my drives were verified with no errors.

How do I find my accounts again?

Comment: Did you run the disk utility restore preferences?

Answer (score 1):

When at the login screen showing just the Guest user hold down <kbd>Option</kbd>  or <kbd>alt</kbd> and the right arrow key.  It will populate more users if they exist.

If that doesn't work you can boot into either [single user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492) (guide to boot to single user) or [Restore partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718) and open terminal.app and run this command:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWFULLNAME -bool yes
```

This will change the login window to be the name and password field.  Then you can enter your username.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>

(not <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> like the first answer from Tron)

That will allow you to type the user name.

(Apple M1 Pro Ventura 13.5.2 (22G91))

My experience:
I had just wiped MDM profiles using the `profilesAreInstalled` method via [Remove a non-removable MDM profile from macOS without a complete wipe](https://graffino.com/til/UmkCdmEx7v-remove-a-non-removable-mdm-profile-from-macos-without-a-complete-wipe).
And then enabled my "guest" along with a "standard" user. Something about non-admin users caused my next restart to only show "Guest User".

I thought I needed to go down the path of deleting my `AppleSetupDone` per [Mac Doesn’t Have Admin Account in macOS Monterey or Big Sur? Here’s a Fix](https://osxdaily.com/2022/03/25/no-admin-account-mac-fix-macos/).
But I think <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> was all I ever needed to do!

Comment: @nohillside my answer is distinct: not `opt + right_arrow` like the first answer, but `opt + return`.